# Can't modify the scrolling speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to reduce the scrolling speed of a website I published: http://www.imbianchinolombardia.it/

The JS code is this one, I really can't seem to isolate the lines of code responsible for the horizontal scrolling speed:

```
/* Toggle next and previous
================================================== */

jQuery(function( $ ){

    $('div.pane').scrollTo( 0 );

    $.scrollTo( 0 );

    var regions = $('section'),
        active_region = 0, prev, next;

    function setup_region ()
    {
        if ( active_region == 0 )
        {
            $('#toggle .previous a').fadeOut('slow');
            prev = regions.size() - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#toggle .previous a').fadeIn('slow');
            prev = active_region - 1;
        }

        if ( active_region == ( regions.size() - 1 ) )
        {
            $('#toggle .next a').fadeOut('slow');
            next = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#toggle .next a').fadeIn('slow');
            next = active_region+1;
        }

        $('#toggle .previous a').attr('href', '#'+ $(regions).eq(prev).attr('id')).click(function(){ active_region = prev; });
        $('#toggle .next a').attr('href', '#'+ $(regions).eq(next).attr('id')).click(function(){ active_region = next; });
    }
    setup_region();

    $('#toggle a').click(function(){

        // prevent click spam
        if ($('*').is(":animated")) return false;

        $.scrollTo( this.hash, 1500, {center:true});
        setup_region();

        return false;

    });

    // bind left and right arrow keys to navigation
    function leftArrowPressed() { $('#toggle .previous a').click(); }
    function rightArrowPressed() { $('#toggle .next a').click(); }
    document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        switch (evt.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                leftArrowPressed();
                break;
            case 39:
                rightArrowPressed();
                break;
        }
    };

});




/* Horizontal Scrolling
================================================== */

;(function( $ ){

    var $scrollTo = $.scrollTo = function( target, duration, settings ){
        $(window).scrollTo( target, duration, settings );
    };

    $scrollTo.defaults = {
        axis:'xy',
        duration: parseFloat($.fn.jquery) >= 1.3 ? 0 : 1
    };

    $scrollTo.window = function( scope ){
        return $(window)._scrollable();
    };

    $.fn._scrollable = function(){
        return this.map(function(){
            var elem = this,
                isWin = !elem.nodeName || $.inArray( elem.nodeName.toLowerCase(), ['iframe','#document','html','body'] ) != -1;

                if( !isWin )
                    return elem;

            var doc = (elem.contentWindow || elem).document || elem.ownerDocument || elem;

            return $.browser.safari || doc.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ?
                doc.body :
                doc.documentElement;
        });
    };

    $.fn.scrollTo = function( target, duration, settings ){
        if( typeof duration == 'object' ){
            settings = duration;
            duration = 0;
        }
        if( typeof settings == 'function' )
            settings = { onAfter:settings };

        if( target == 'max' )
            target = 9e9;

        settings = $.extend( {}, $scrollTo.defaults, settings );

        duration = duration || settings.speed || settings.duration;

        settings.queue = settings.queue && settings.axis.length > 1;

        if( settings.queue )

            duration /= 2;
        settings.offset = both( settings.offset );
        settings.over = both( settings.over );

        return this._scrollable().each(function(){
            var elem = this,
                $elem = $(elem),
                targ = target, toff, attr = {},
                win = $elem.is('html,body');

            switch( typeof targ ){

                case 'number':
                case 'string':
                    if( /^([+-]=)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?$/.test(targ) ){
                        targ = both( targ );
                        break;
                    }

                    targ = $(targ,this);
                case 'object':

                    if( targ.is || targ.style )

                        toff = (targ = $(targ)).offset();
            }
            $.each( settings.axis.split(''), function( i, axis ){
                var Pos = axis == 'x' ? 'Left' : 'Top',
                    pos = Pos.toLowerCase(),
                    key = 'scroll' + Pos,
                    old = elem[key],
                    max = $scrollTo.max(elem, axis);

                if( toff ){
                    attr[key] = toff[pos] + ( win ? 0 : old - $elem.offset()[pos] );

                    if( settings.margin ){
                        attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('margin'+Pos)) || 0;
                        attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('border'+Pos+'Width')) || 0;
                    }

                    attr[key] += settings.offset[pos] || 0;

                    if (settings.center) {
                    var dimKey = axis== 'x' ? 'width' : 'height';
                    attr[key] -= ($elem[dimKey]() - targ[dimKey]()) / 2;
                    }

                    if( settings.over[pos] )

                        attr[key] += targ[axis=='x'?'width':'height']() * settings.over[pos];
                }else{
                    var val = targ[pos];

                    attr[key] = val.slice && val.slice(-1) == '%' ?
                        parseFloat(val) / 100 * max
                        : val;
                }

                if( /^\d+$/.test(attr[key]) )

                    attr[key] = attr[key] <= 0 ? 0 : Math.min( attr[key], max );

                if( !i && settings.queue ){

                    if( old != attr[key] )

                        animate( settings.onAfterFirst );

                    delete attr[key];
                }
            });

            animate( settings.onAfter );

            function animate( callback ){
                $elem.animate( attr, duration, settings.easing, callback && function(){
                    callback.call(this, target, settings);
                });
            };

        }).end();
    };

    $scrollTo.max = function( elem, axis ){
        var Dim = axis == 'x' ? 'Width' : 'Height',
            scroll = 'scroll'+Dim;

        if( !$(elem).is('html,body') )
            return elem[scroll] - $(elem)[Dim.toLowerCase()]();

        var size = 'client' + Dim,
            html = elem.ownerDocument.documentElement,
            body = elem.ownerDocument.body;

        return Math.max( html[scroll], body[scroll] )
             - Math.min( html[size]  , body[size]   );

    };

    function both( val ){
        return typeof val == 'object' ? val : { top:val, left:val };
    };

})( jQuery );
```

Is anyone able to point me to the correct line and how could I proceed to modify it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: With that link you provided there is no scrolling at all.

Comment: That's too much code. Can't you reduce it to the relevant part that does the scrolling which is working unexpected?

Comment: Hi @Bergi I can't for the fact that I'm a graphic designer and I don't have a great grasp on JS code so I can't isolate the code!

Comment: Who did write the code then? Please ask the person who is responsible for it.

Comment: Hey @zazvorniki if you click on the right arrow in the lower part of the screen it should scroll to the right.

Comment: I've removed part of the unneeded code anyway

Comment: When I click on the button in my browser it does not scroll, on my iPad it makes the while screen flicker. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on is that your third anchor point is much further away from the second point, than the second is from the first.

The scroll duration is set to 1500 (1.5 seconds).

`$.scrollTo( this.hash, 1500, {center:true});`

So, it isn't about speed, it's about duration.  The duration is the same, but the distances are different.  You can increase that number to slow it down.

Comment: Thank you Javalsu, you've solved my problem!